# how to use Rxjs filter in angular along with BehaviorSubject

Tags: typescript, rxjs, behaviorsubject, rxjs-filter

I have an array that looks as follows.

```
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'a',
      status: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'b',
      status: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'c',
      status: false,
    },
  ];
```

I have created `BehaviorSubject` by setting the initial value as the above array.

I want to get the array of data, which status should be true by using `rxjs pipe operator`.
So,  the filter process should happen before subscribing to the observable.

I have tried ith the following

```
 subject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(this.data);
  constructor() {
    this.getSubject()
      .pipe(filter((x) => x.status))
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }

  getSubject() {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

Expected output

```
   [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'a',
      status: true,
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'b',
      status: true,
    }]
```

Comment: offtopic: Try to avoid the `any`-type. Read [this](https://codeburst.io/does-any-harm-typescript-c811ad3b00e8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your behaviour subject is returning an Array and rxjs filter is applied on observable not array. You need to apply filter after getting array from observable

```
this.getSubject()
  .pipe(map((arr) => arr.filter(x => x.status)))
  .subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: So I need to use array filter operation along with rxjs map operator right ?

Comment: It's working fine. Thank u. Now I want to convert the response to  object from array

Comment: What is your expected reponse of object?

Comment: @SufailKalathil I believe `from` may be what you want, see the end of my answer.

Comment: @zainhassan 
{
id:1,
name:'a',
status:true
}

consider only  one status field true

Comment: You can arr.find() which will return object instead of array

Answer (score 1):

You are emitting an array of values rather than the values one by one. You can use `map` to operate on the array. Also, you can call `pipe` directly on the subject.

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subject
      .pipe(map((x: any[]) => x.filter((x: any) => x.status)))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

As a side note, you can convert an array directly to an observable using `from` and `of`.

`of` will emit the entire array when subscribed to.

```js
  data$ = of(this.data);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$
      .pipe(map((x: any[]) => x.filter((x) => x.status)))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

This logs:

```
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
```

`from` will emit the values one by one when subscribed to.

```js
  data$ = from(this.data);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data$.pipe(filter((x: any) => x.status)).subscribe((res: any) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

This logs:

```
Object { id: 1, name: "a", status: true }
Object { id: 1, name: "b", status: true }
```

Comment: Thanks for the notes. But in my case, I need to use subject  instead of `from` and `of`